# Apollo: Unknown type 'contact_id', did you mean 'contactType' or 'Contact'

Tags: flutter, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I use `"apollo-server": "^2.9.11"` and have the following schema to upload a file in multipart

```js
type Mutation {
    ...
    updateProfileImage(contact_id: ID!, file: Upload!): String!
}
```

And when I query it using `graphql_flutter 2.1.0` client I get the following error:

`Unknown type 'contact_id', did you mean 'ContactType' or 'Contact'`

Although it was working with `file` argument (streams and uploads the file) before I added `contact_id` argument (which I need in the resolver).

Is there any restrictions when uploading files with Apollo like not adding other arguments? or there is another cause for this?

**update: Query**

On flutter side I'm sending like this:

```
r”“”
   mutation($contactId : contact_id , $file: Upload!){
     uploadProfileImage(contact_id: $contactId ,file: $file)
   }
“”"
```

Although it was working (file was uploading) when the query was like this:

```
r”“”
   mutation($file: Upload!){
     uploadProfileImage(file: $file)
   }
“”"
```

But after adding the `contact_id` argument to my schema and query, I started to get that error.

Comment: Sounds like your query is malformed. Please update your question to include the code that's actually sending the query.

Comment: @DanielRearden updated.

Comment: So... why does the `$contactId` variable have a type of `contact_id`? Presumably, like the error indicates, you don't have a type with that name.

Comment: yeah i figured after I posted it, thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

So I just changed the `$contactId` variable type to `ID!` in the query and it worked.

```
r”“”
   mutation($contactId : ID! , $file: Upload!){
     uploadProfileImage(contact_id: $contactId ,file: $file)
   }
“”"
```